# scrapy framework : login-scrape-navigate

Tags: scrapy

How to do form login and then work with that session using scrapy?

For e.g. Consider a website which has login authentication and it has three different pages linked with login session.
So using scrapy, first login and then scrape some in home page then follow the specific link available in the home page, hit the link and scrape from that page. Then come back to home page again follow another link and so on.
I have a file ccbank_spider.py, below are the content

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):

 #some code

 #for hitting and parsing of the Account URL
 for accountURL in (strip(s) for itemArr in items for s in itemArr['accountURL']):
    print accountURL
    yield request(accountURL, callback=self.account_transactions)

 def account_transactions(self, response):
  print 'print text'
  return None
```

i get the below error

```
          File "D:\NextGen\workspace\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\ccbank_spider.py", line       45, in after_login
       yield request(accountURL, callback=self.account_transactions)
   exceptions.TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: there are so many posts on SO regarding this have you tried to look in related questions?

Comment: @kishore i have tried it. All posts are specific to crawling. So only i posted a exact example for which i need a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from documentation about your first question (login):

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return

        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

As for the other part of your question you can scrape all the links you want to also scrape form home page and do for every new request:

```
request = Request(url_to_scrape, callback=self.parse_item)
    request.meta['language'] = "eng"
    yield request
```

And then you parse that page in parse_item in this exaxmple, also you can send meta information to it as you can see.

Comment: i have made use of your code. i got error on Request(url_to_scrape, callback=self.parse_item) because Request was not having a callback parameter so i imported from scrapy.http import request and used it. Now i get the error, which i have updated the content please help.